Stochastic convergence to a non-stochastic convergent sequence
I have a sequence of non-negative estimators $\{\hat{\theta}_n\}$, and I have established that $\hat{\theta}_n = \theta_n + \mathcal{O}_{P}(n^{-1})$ for any fixed $n$. While $\theta_n \in\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$ is a constant for fixed $n$, $\{\theta_n\}$ is itself a (non-stochastic) sequence.
I can also establish that $\theta_n \to \theta$ (in the usual sense) as $n\to\infty$ where $\theta \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$ is also a constant.
Am I able to make a statement such as $\hat{\theta}_n = \theta + \mathcal{O}_P(n^{-1})$ with perhaps an additional asymptotic term to account for the rate of convergence of $\theta_n \to \theta$?
My thinking so far is to use the expression
$$|\hat{\theta}_n - \theta| = |\hat{\theta}_n - \theta_n + \theta_n - \theta| \leq |\hat{\theta}_n - \theta_n| + |\theta_n - \theta|$$
and then bound both terms separately on the right and study the result. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

You can prove convergence in probability. Take $\varepsilon>0$ and pick $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $|\theta_n - \theta|< \frac\varepsilon2$ for all $n>N$. Then for all $n>N$,
$$\mathbb P[|\hat{\theta}_n - \theta|>\varepsilon]\le \mathbb P[|\hat{\theta}_n - \theta_n| + |\theta_n - \theta|>\varepsilon]\le \mathbb P\left[|\hat{\theta}_n - \theta_n|>\frac\varepsilon2\right]\to 0.$$
I'm not familiar with your notation $\mathcal{O}_{P}(n^{-1})$ but maybe you can say something about the rate of convergence using this.
